# An error occurs in an example of learning “closure” in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures

I am learning JavaScript now. I found an example online and run in in Atom. Unfortunately, an error shows up saying 'Unexpected token, expected , (17:0)'. Could anyone tell me how to fix the code with explanations?

Thank you very much in advance.

```
    var globalVar = "abc"; 


    (function outerFunction (outerArg) { 

        var outerFuncVar = 'x';    

        (function innerFunction (innerArg) { 
            var innerFuncVar = "y"; 
            console.log(          
                "outerArg = " + outerArg + "\n" +
                "outerFuncVar = " + outerFuncVar + "\n" +
                "innerArg = " + innerArg + "\n" +
                "innerFuncVar = " + innerFuncVar + "\n" +
                "globalVar = " + globalVar);
     
        }
    }
```

And expected results are:

```
    outerArg = 7
    outerFuncVar = x
    innerArg = 5`enter code here`
    innerFuncVar = y
    globalVar = abc
```

Comment: make sure that you have no orphaned brackets or braces

Answer (score 0):

there is a couple of missing `)` at the end of the function

this should do it

```js
var globalVar = "abc";

// Parent self invoking function
(function outerFunction (outerArg) { // begin of scope outerFunction
  // Variable declared in outerFunction function scope
  var outerFuncVar = 'x';
  // Closure self-invoking function
  (function innerFunction (innerArg) { // begin of scope innerFunction
    // variable declared in innerFunction function scope
    var innerFuncVar = "y";
    console.log(
        "outerArg = " + outerArg + "\n" +
        "outerFuncVar = " + outerFuncVar + "\n" +
        "innerArg = " + innerArg + "\n" +
        "innerFuncVar = " + innerFuncVar + "\n" +
        "globalVar = " + globalVar);

  })(5)// end of scope innerFunction)(5); // Pass 5 as parameter
})(7)
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, mena happy. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed some brackets, As you are using self invoking function.

```
(function() {
   // code
})();
```

As you can see above, the following pair of parentheses converts the code inside the parentheses into an expression:

```
function(){...}
```

the next pair, i.e. the second pair of parentheses continues the operation. It calls the function.
Please check your running example.

```js
var globalVar = "abc";
// Parent self invoking function
(function outerFunction (outerArg) { // begin of scope outerFunction
    // Variable declared in outerFunction function scope
    var outerFuncVar = 'x';
    // Closure self-invoking function
    (function innerFunction (innerArg) { // begin of scope innerFunction
        // variable declared in innerFunction function scope
        var innerFuncVar = "y";
        console.log(
            "outerArg = " + outerArg + "\n" +
            "outerFuncVar = " + outerFuncVar + "\n" +
            "innerArg = " + innerArg + "\n" +
            "innerFuncVar = " + innerFuncVar + "\n" +
            "globalVar = " + globalVar);

    }// end of scope innerFunction)(5); // Pass 5 as parameter
    )(5);
    })(5);
```